# Using jQuery in Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular

I have this simple javascript file 'my.js' inside src folder of my Angular app

```
slideDown(id) {
   $('#' + id).slideToggle();
}
```

I want to call this function like this

```
<div class="view-details" (click)="slideDown('theID')">
```

I have looked everywhere and i cannot figure it out how to include my.js to the components

Any hint will do

PS: New to Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working sample project which is implemented to satisfy your requirement: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkxmjprrnp

There are two main files which involved in performing this functionality:

*1. the `my.js` file*

```js
function slideDown(i) {
  alert(
    "You've already used this function from my.js! The passed value is: " + i
  );
 $("#abc").html("I've been changed by using jquery");
}

export default slideDown;
```

2. *the `app.component.ts` file which import and use the `my.js` file*

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import slideDown from "../my";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Welcome to Stack Overflow, Dimitris Kounarakis!</h2>
    <button (click)="handleClick()">Click me</button>
    <h4 id="abc">Hello</h4>
  </div>
 `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  handleClick() {
    slideDown(2);
  }
}
```

3. in the `index.html` file, we have to include the jquery library
   using CDN:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Angular</title>
 <base href="/">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer! It works fine but.. I updated my question and i get an error '$ is not defined'. It seems it cannot recognize jquery..

Comment: then the question now is almost completely different from the old one.

Comment: ahh.. sorry for being a nood in angular and not included from the beggining.. didnt think it would be a problem

Comment: ok, then I just updated the answer and CodeSandbox project. Now it can understand the `$` syntax from jquery. Hopefully, it helps

Comment: Whats the difference from including jquery in angular.json?

Comment: Honestly, this is the first time I were trying to use jQuery in Angular project. In the process of finding a solution for you, I also saw people including jquery in `angular.json` file. However, when comparing to the way we using jQuery CDN in index.html, I choose using jQuery CDN because of it's  simplicity. Btw, for now, I cannot provide a complete answer for your question. I think that's a good question, then you could add a new question to Stack Overflow. I think someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this below steps

```
1) First add a reference of your external JS file for importing it to the component. 
   import * as my from '../../src/assets/my.js';

2) Now declare a "var" of the same name that your function has inside external JS.
   declare var slideDown: any;

3) ngOninit(){
    slideDown();
   }
```

If you want to access inside template. You can assign to public variable.
this.slideDown = slideDown;